# "pointer name" does not name a type error

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

**Im new to C++**. I get error on the statements marked  `//this shows error` but its alternative (marked as `but this works` ). Can someone explain this please?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node *next;
    int data;
};

class Que
{
public:
    //this shows error
    /* 
    Node *front, *rear;
    front = NULL;
    rear = NULL;
    */

    //but this works
    Node *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;
};
```

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: okay next time i will correct it. Thanks! @Evg

Comment: It's the difference between a declaration of a member with initialisation (`Node *front = NULL`) and assignment (`front = NULL`, which relies on `front` having being previously declared).    An assignment is only permitted within a function.    Initialisation is permitted when the name is declared/defined, and a declaration is possible in both a class definition and within a function (among others).

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your reply. So you mean its better to declare with initialisation or else use function/constructor. Right?

Comment: @CamsBoyfriend -   That's the way it works out if, by "better", you mean "valid in rules of the language".   What you were attempting is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These:

```
front = NULL;
rear = NULL;
```

are assignment [statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements). And this:

```
Node *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;
```

is a declaration (definition, initialization) statement using [in-class initializers](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-classes#member-init).

Assignment statements are not allowed to appear in the class declaration body, whereas the initialization statements are.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function or a class constructor to **initialize** the class objects:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node *next;
    int data;
};

class Que
{
public:
    Que() {
        Node *front, *rear;
        front = NULL;
        rear = NULL;
    }
};
```

In the aforementioned code, the `front` and `rear` have now a storage class since they're in constructor which is acting like a function.

---

To clarify better, you may use the following code:

```
class test {
public:
    int x;    // declaring a variable outside of a constructor or function
    x = 10;   // initialization is not allowed here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NULL nullptr
class Node
{
public:
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

class Que1 {
public: //Method 1 - initializer list
    Node* front{ NULL }, * rear{ NULL };
};
class Que2 {
public: //Method 2 - assignment operator for initialization
    Node* front = NULL, * rear = NULL;
};
class Que3 {
public: //Method 3 - initializer list at constructor
    Node* front, * rear;
    Que3() : front{ NULL }, rear{ NULL }
    {}
};
class Que4 {
public: //Method 4 - assignment after member intialization/construction
    Node* front, * rear;
    Que4()
    {
        front = NULL;
        rear = NULL;
    }
};
```

Your assignments were not on a function's body. since you tried to initialize, I thought about showing different syntax.
method 1 is the most preferred one.